# there is a link to wechat comment page, but the content got by capture software and 'get' request is different

Tags: python, fiddler, wechat

I want to crawl the comments of the WeChat public account article.So I used fiddler to capture the WeChat public account.But through the same comment page link，i get the different web content，i want to know why this is the result?
I want to put two pictures, but I don't know why it is not allowed.

Comment: You have to copy also all the headers including cookies, authentication tokens, ...

Comment: the headers including "host" and "use-agent" is not enough? and the  needed authentication tokens i have already passed in ...

Comment: You know that you can copy the complete captured request by drag&drop it to to compose tab? This should replay it exactly.